# iOS app name expiration and resetting the clock

Tags: ios, app-store

I registered an app name a few months ago but never submitted a binary. Now Apple says I have a week to submit a binary or the name will become available to other developers. **Will submitting a binary and developer-rejecting it reset the clock?**

I know that submitting a binary that's reviewed and rejected by Apple resets the clock as this happened to another app of mine. However I'm curious what happens when the developer rejects it.

Answer (score 1):

After registering your app you have 120 days time frame to submit the binary for review. If that expires then you have to register the app again and you may or may not be able to use the previously name in new registration.

Here is what apple doc's say about that:

> App Name Expiry
>
> Once you have created your app, and it is in the state Prepare For
>   Upload or Waiting     For Upload, you will have 120 days (4 months)
>   from your creation date in iTunes Connect, to deliver a binary to
>   Apple.
>
> If you do not deliver a binary before the 120-day deadline, your app
>   will be deleted from iTunes Connect.
>
> As a result of this deletion, your app name will be able to be used by
>   another developer and you cannot reuse the app name, SKU or Bundle ID.
>
> See the Deleting an App section of this guide to learn more about the
>   ramifications of App Delete.